# Python package for SMOTEBoosting algorithm

Tags: python, imbalanced-data, imblearn

I am looking for a Python package that implements the SMOTEBoosting algorithm. But I only find SMOTE in imbalanced-learn.

Comment: `SMOTE-Boost` is an open issue on `imblearn` (see [issue #105](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn/issues/105)). Contributions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Find [here](https://github.com/dialnd/imbalanced-algorithms) an implementation of SMOTEBoost based on `sklearn`'s [AdaBoost](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier.html) API.

Note looking at the source, this library supports binary problem only

```
...
if minority_target is None:
            # Determine the minority class label.
            stats_c_ = Counter(y)
            maj_c_ = max(stats_c_, key=stats_c_.get)
            min_c_ = min(stats_c_, key=stats_c_.get)
            self.minority_target = min_c_
        else:
            self.minority_target = minority_target
....
```